# AS3 rpc call doesn't seem to be working once published to website

Tags: actionscript-3

So this is really weird. I have a SWF that makes a few web service calls. When running it through flash builder or even double clicking the swf and have it running in IE it works fine. But once I actually publish it to our web site it seems the rpc call fails but doesn't call the failure handler. It seems just nothing happens.

I tried debugging it but it only gets as far as making the call and then nothing else since the reset of the code is based on the success of the call.

Is there any other way of debugging this?

EDIT:
It turns out I am getting an error. 
Error: Request for resource at https://xxxx.asmx?WSDL by requestor from http:// localhost:58432 /xxxx/xxx.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.

I do have the following crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

and my I'm using Security.loadPolicyFile("https://www.xxx.com/crossdomain.xml");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my crossdomain to this and now it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" />
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" to-ports="80, 8080, 443"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```